# WordPress related content by category yields same results for every post in custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title says, I'm filtering my WordPress related content by category for custom post types. I get results, but on each post page, the related content list is the same, even if the categories are completely different. I want it to correctly show results for each post type based on category.

I've tried the below code and many variations of it. I've even tried plugins such as YARPP, but even they produce the same posts on each page, regardless of categories.

```
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $cat_ids = array();
        $categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

        if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
            foreach ($categories as $category):
            array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
        endforeach;
        endif;

        $current_post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
        $query_args = array(

                            'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
                            'post_type'      => array($current_post_type),
                            'post__not_in'    => array($post_id),
                            'posts_per_page'  => '5',
                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                            'orderby' => 'rand'


                            );

        $related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );

        if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
            while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): array_push($posts, $related_cats_post->the_post());

    ?>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile;
    return $posts;
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    }
```

I expect the above code to work correctly - I believe it may have even worked correctly at one point. I'm just wondering if there's anything that may cause the list of related posts to be the same on every single post?

Comment: Caching, maybe?

Comment: I tried clearing the cache - so far no luck :(

Comment: I just spotted what seems to be a bug in your code: shouldn't `is_wp_error($categories)` be `!is_wp_error($categories)` instead?

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks - good catch, however, it didn't resolve the issue unfortunately.